# Improve prestashop site page speed

Tags: performance, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi i want improve prestashop page speed 
i tried following thing

1. https://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/10-best-tips-to-speed-up-your-prestashop-store-3/
2. Speed Up your Site and compression with htaccess file (also tries this )
3. minfied css & js
4. use cdn (but not working )

Is there any way for do this  currently page speed is 11.6  i need it 4-5.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which uses PrestaShop version ? What is your theme? you've tried to see if your hosting has plans PrestaShop optimization ?

Comment: Doesn't GTMetrix advise you to do more? Like image compression, image sizes etc...?

Comment: @Julien Lachal check  https://gtmetrix.com/reports/optimize1.crazygadgets.co.nz/7rCZT2B4

Comment: "Specify image dimensions" and try again, it costs a lot on PageSpeed as well as "Serve scaled images"

Comment: @ Matteo Ennai use buzz theme and using hosting https://www.crazydomains.co.nz

Comment: well i am new in ps  how i specify like edit image from backend then add dimensions

Comment: try to use https://gtmetrix.com

Comment: thanks @Matteo Enna  i use but speed is same  i also use https://kraken.io/account/optimizer/cruncher optimeized image but no success  i dont, want use paid cdn

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Prestashop Profiling](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/PrestaShop's+developer+tools) system to see if there are long running SQL queries or if a hook is taking too much time.

To enable Prestashop Profiling you should edit your `/config/defines.inc.php` file and turn line `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', false);` to `define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);`.

We can't help you further without more informations.

---

Ok, so this is not just a problem of optimization of your code. I can see that you added a cdn `optimize1.`, Prestashop allows you to add 3 different cdn, you should use this option (it will allows parallels downloads of your content). [Here is some information on the subject](https://gtmetrix.com/parallelize-downloads-across-hostnames.html).

Comment: Thanks for ans  but  i add this but no sucess . please check this and guide me.https://gtmetrix.com/reports/optimize1.crazygadgets.co.nz/AyKuVfJh

Comment: sorry but i can,t find plese give me  a link

Comment: check my reports http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1444127/943caa16d446dce37c03ba18f07142c2